# Выделение памяти под неинициализированные переменные

Tags: c, память

Подскажите пожалуйста, выделяется ли память под переменные если они просто объявлены, но им не присвоены конкретные значения. Например, написал просто int x,y,z и при этом их не использовал никак по ходу программы.

Comment: компилятор - выкинет их, если они не используются. И, даже инициализированные - выкинет при оптимизации, если они тоже не используются.

Answer (score 5):

Если не использовали вообще - то умный оптимизатор их выбросит, не выделив память. Если вы использовали `x` для чтения без предварительной записи, а перед этим просто написали `int x;` не в глобальной области видимости - место будет выделено, но не инициализировано, о чем умный компилятор должен бы предупредить - об использовании неинициализированной переменной.

Кусочек из книжки "С. Справочник. Полное описание языка":

Объявление объекта является определением, если оно выделяет память для объекта. Объявления, которые включают инициализаторы, всегда являются определениями. Кроме того, все объявления в блоке функции являются определениями, если только они не содержат спецификатор класса памяти `extern.` Вот несколько примеров:

```
int a = 10;         // Определение a.
extern double b[];  // Объявление массива b, определенного
                    // в другом месте программы.
void func()
{
    extern char c;  // Объявление, но не определение c.
    static short d; // Определение d.
    float e;        // Определение e.
    /* ... */
}
```

Если вы объявляете объект за пределами всех функций, без инициализатора и без спецификатора памяти `extern`, такое объявление является предполагаемым определением (tentative definition). Вот несколько примеров:

```
int i, v[];   // Предполагаемые определения i, v и j.
static int j;
```

Предполагаемое определение идентификатора остается простым объявлением, если единица трансляции содержит еще одно определение того же самого идентификатора. Если же нет, то компилятор ведет себя так, как будто предполагаемое определение включает инициализатор с нулевым значением, что делает его определением. Таким образом, переменные `i` и `j` типа `int` в предыдущем примере, идентификаторы которых объявляются без инициализаторов, неявно инициализируются значением 0, а массив `v` с типом элементов `int` имеет один элемент с исходным значением 0.

Comment: Стоит дополнить, что если в разных единицах компиляции есть определения внешних переменных с одинаковыми именами (т.е. явно инициализируем в нескольких единицах), то линкер будет ругаться `multiple definition`, а если инициализации нигде нет (или только в одном файле), то все ОК. Причем, типы у таких переменных в разных файлах **могут быть разными** (однако, если правила выравнивания не совпадают, то линкер выдаст warning)

Answer (score 2):

Вы неявно предполагаете, что компилятор честно выделяет память под каждую переменную в отдельности. Это уже давно не так.

Современные оптимизаторы могут поместить любую переменную в регистры, в общую область памяти с другой переменной, если их время жизни не пересекается, или вовсе преобразовать код и исключить переменную. Поэтому не имеет смысла экономить на переменных, компилятор всё сделает правильно и экономно.

---

[Пример](https://godbolt.org/g/bFWBzW): вот такой код

```
int f()
{
    int x = 5, y = 8;
    x += y;
    y = 7 * x;
    return x + y;
}
```

intel compiler 17 компилирует в

```
push      104
pop       rax
ret
```

а gcc 6.3 в

```
mov     eax, 104
ret
```

Вы видите, что компилятор выкинул вообще все переменные и вычисления.

Answer (score 0):

Например, такой код завершается аварийно (MinGW)

```
int main()
{
    double v[1000000];
    return 0;
}
```

В данном случае видимо выделяется. По ходу переполнение стека.

Comment: да, конечно http://ideone.com/okYEJX

Comment: Зависит от конкретного компилятора/оптимизатора...

Comment: Компилируйте с ключем -O